# Excluding Layouts in express but keeping CSS

Tags: javascript, express

I cant seem to find a way to exclude my layout in express. I tried doing

```
response.render("index",{layout: false});
```

but that disables the css for the page. Is there something im missing here? What is the best way to disable the layout but keep the css?

Also, I'm using 
 `app.use(express.static("public"));` 
  and my css is in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your layout is including the CSS. Try instead making a layout that just has the code to include your css and nothing else. Like so:

```
/* Using handlebars templateing for this example */
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
{{{ body }}}
```

This will just include the css and then display your content.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />` is the code to include your css

`{{{ body }}}` is the code to include your content.

However it is not possible to include css without a layout unless it is in your content.

So if you want to use `{layout: false}` the css inclusion code(`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />`) has to be in your content

Comment: Alright. My layout is just as what you said, just the css and {{{body}}}. But the same issues occuring. The CSS on the home page isnt working. I forgot to also include, the CSS on the other pages are working fine. Just the homepage is being affected. :\

Comment: Can you join this collab session on JS fiddle, would be easier to help **Removed link to help prevent spam**